# How would I get convert this std::string into a std::basic string?

Tags: c++, string, std, memcpy, strcpy

Currently I have a `std:::string` called `cipher_line` that I get from the process of:

```
string str_cipher_line;
// Get the Offline Mount Point
ifstream ifs1;
ifs1.open(offlineMountPoint.c_str());

if (ifs1.is_open()) {
    getline(ifs1, str_cipher_line);
} else {
    cout << "unable to open file" << endl;
    return 1;
}

ifs1.close();
```

Now I want to be able to get a `secure_string` from `cipher_line`. `secure_string` is defined below:

```
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, zallocator<char> > secure_string;
```

I don't understand how to do this. Should I employ `memcpy` or `strcpy`?

Comment: Neither. Use the constructor that takes a beginning and an ending iterator, and pass in `std::string`'s `begin()`, and `end()`.

Comment: yeah, could you elaborate on that as an answer @SamVarshavchik

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default constructing them and then changing them. That is, change `ifstream ifs1; ifs1.open(whatever);` to `ifstream ifs1(whatever);`. And you don’t need to call `ifs1.close()`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks, good advice is always welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::basic_string` [iterator constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (6 on cppreference) to construct from `secure_string` or `std::copy`. The same applies the other way around.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct some_other_allocator : std::allocator<T>{};

using other_string = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, some_other_allocator<char>>;

int main() {
    other_string string1("hello");

    //using std::string constructor
    std::string string2(string1.begin(),string1.end());

    std::string string2_copy;
    //using std::copy
    std::copy(string1.begin(),string1.end(),std::back_inserter(string2_copy));

    std::cout << string1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << string2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << string2_copy << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/pCuol5)

Comment: Your answer code shows how to construct `secure_string` (or `other_string` in your code) from a string literal, but I think the questioner wanted to see how to construct it from `std::string`: `secure_string myString{str_cipher_line.begin(), str_cipher_line.end()};`